# Locally mid-convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function such that it exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ with $|x-y|>\varepsilon$, one has that $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$. Recall that a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is said mid-convex if $g(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq\frac{g(x)+g(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

My question is: Is $f$ mid-convex?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f(x)=\vert \vert x \vert -1\vert$. You’ll verify that $f$ satisfies your criteria for $\epsilon =100$. However, $f$ is not mid convex.

*A too small bump...*

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you very much. I have modificated the question to know what happens if we suppose that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I would suggest that you validate this answer and open another question. It is very hard to understand an answer of a moving target question!